# Is there a Javascript equivalent to the Ruby syntax using underscores (e.g. 10_000 = 10000) to make larger integers human readable?

Tags: javascript, syntax, integer

In Ruby you may say:

```
n = 10_000
```

or

```
n = 10000
```

They are identical. I think you can also do something like this in Perl. This is a very nifty thing, to make large numbers more human readable.

My question is really two parts:

1. Is there a Javascript equivalent? Because I would definitely use it.
2. What do you call this underscore character, syntactically? I bet an experienced programmer can field this pretty easily, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to use the internet for a reverse dictionary. Such information I think would be useful to me in learning future languages. And it's absolutely driving me crazy, that I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: 1) No. 2) "Place separator", perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, there is not. At least not the way ruby does it. If you're familiar with [scientific notation/E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), you can turn a large number like `1000000000000000` into something more friendly like `1E15`

As a sidenote: There has been a long-going discussion for coffeescript to include something similar to the ruby syntax [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2192)

2) It is called an underscore and has no special name in its role in Ruby integer literals. The only thing special in Ruby (and in [Perl](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch02_02.htm#INDEX-121), [Frink](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/#NumericTypes), [Caml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caml) and others) is that underscores in integer literals are ignored. This feature is very old and was first used in [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) to make integer literals [more readable](http://www.gavilan.edu/csis/languages/literals.html#_Toc75869974).

Comment: Note that numeric separators are now supported in Typescript (as of v2.7) and are at stage 3 as an EcmaScript proposal (so not yet adopted as an official part of the language, but likely to be in the future) and are coming soon to Chrome/V8: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator

Answer (score 7):

Numeric Separators are now a feature of Javascript. ()

So, yes, `n = 10_000` is the same as `n = 10000` (`n = 1_0_0_0_0` works too...)

Numeric Separators also work with Binary Literals and Hex Literals.
Relevant doc: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator

At the time of writing, browser support is not excellent though, [see caniuse](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=Numeric%20Separators).

Node 12.8.1 and above supports them.