# tanstack react query retryDelay not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

There is some data that I want to fetch every 30 seconds (if successful)
and I also want to retry fetch exponentially by 60 seconds (each retry has is 60 seconds longer, with the retry no longer happening after 10 mins of retry) if unsuccessful.

I have followed the docs but it seems to be not working no matter what, there are no new request in the network tab no matter how much I wait.

Here's what I've done so far:

I set up defaults for my client

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retryDelay: (attemptIndex) => Math.min(60_000 * 2 ** attemptIndex, 600_000),
    },
  },
})
```

when this didn't work I added it individually (with default value and also without default value):

```
const {data} = useQuery({
    queryKey: // queryKey,
    queryFn: // queryFn,
    enabled: !!id,
    refetchInterval: 30_000,
    retryDelay: (attemptIndex) => Math.min(60_000 * 2 ** attemptIndex, 600_000),
})
```

when that did not work I ended up trying a different method:

```
const {data} = useQuery({
    queryKey: // queryKey,
    queryFn: // queryFn,
    enabled: !!id,
    refetchInterval: (query) => query.state.status === 'error' ? Math.min(60_000 * 2 ** query.state.fetchFailureCount, 600_000) : 30_000,
})
```

Though this does work, its not what I am looking for

```
refetchInterval: (query) => query.state.status === 'error' ? 60_000 : 30_000,
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: Why do you have _ in 600_000?

Comment: It is called a numeric separator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525292/numeric-literals-with-underscores-in-javascript @BhaveshParvatkar

Answer (score 0):

The values of retry should be in milliseconds. In your initial code you were using 1000 which turns into 1 minute.

So your retryDelay should be: `return Math.min(60000 * 2 ** attemptIndex, 600000);`

Stopping after a particular time is not possible. However, based on your retry duration logic we can assume that after 3 attempts 10 minutes will already be passed. So you can add logic to retry based on the failureCount.

You can use the following code:

NOTE: failureCount starts with 0

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retryDelay: (attemptIndex) => {
        return Math.min(60000 * 2 ** attemptIndex, 600000);
      },
      retry: (failureCount) => {
        return failureCount < 4;
      },
      refetchInterval: 30000,
    },
  },
});
```

In case you want this logic only to specific API then you should add it in useQuery.

```
useQuery({
    queryKey: ["test"],
    queryFn: () => {},
    retryDelay: (attemptIndex) => {
      return Math.min(60000 * 2 ** attemptIndex, 600000);
    },
    retry: (failureCount) => {
      return failureCount < 4;
    },
    refetchInterval: 30000,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
  });
```

Comment: I changed the delay time for testing. The retry was 60_000, not 1000 like the code you provided; which did not work.

Also, if we are doing exponential backoff by 60 seconds, it should take 6 attempts not 3. Nonetheless it's still not sending new requests after failing.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible demo to debug? Maybe in codesandbox.